# How to test JUnit test case for primefaces UploadedFile component

Tags: java, jsf, junit

I want to test the file upload component using the JUnit test case.I there any ay to get the mock implementation for UploadedFile.i am using the below ode to read the uploaded file from the UI.

```
public void XXXX(final FileUploadEvent event) {

        final String uniqueFolderName = this.getUniqueFolderName();

        final org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();

        final UploadedFileWrapper uploadedFileWrapper = new UploadedFileWrapper(uploadedFile,
                UploadedFile.Status.FILE_SAVED, uniqueFolderName);

        if (!new Boolean(this.multiple)) {
            LOGGER.debug("only single upload is allowed", this.getMultiple());
            this.clearUploadedFiles();
        }

        this.uploadedFiles.add(uploadedFileWrapper);
    }
```

could you please help me how to create mock implementation for this component.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it's done with Mockito:

```
    File file = new File("src/test/TestUploadFile.txt");
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileUploadEvent event = Mockito.mock(FileUploadEvent.class);
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = Mockito.mock(UploadedFile.class);
    Mockito.when(uploadedFile.getFileName()).thenReturn(file.getName());
    Mockito.when(uploadedFile.getContentType()).thenReturn("application/octet-stream");
    Mockito.when(uploadedFile.getInputstream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
    Mockito.when(event.getFile()).thenReturn(uploadedFile);
```

I pull a test file and create an inputStream. Then I mock FileUploadEvent and UploadedFile and set the specific attributes that I needed, you may need to mock out more attributes.

Comment: Just add this also: Mockito.when(uploadedFile.getSize()).thenReturn(file.length());

Answer (score 1):

```
Did you try..

// Creating a Mock for UploadedFile 
UploadedFile mockFileUploadedFile = EasyMock.createMock(UploadedFile.class);

// Injecting the Mock to FileUploadEvent 
FileUploadEvent fileUploadEvent = new instance...
fileUploadEvent.setFileUploadedFile(mockFileUploadedFile)
```

Comment: Just a tip, [`FileUploadEvent` class](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/event/FileUploadEvent.html) needs the uploaded file to be passed in its constructor.